# ssh login does not display motd while UsePAM = no

Tags: bash, ssh, motd

I have customized `/etc/motd` and it was displaying it correctly while login via `ssh`:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab141.3 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is out, raising the bar on performance, security,
   and optimisation for Intel, AMD, Nvidia, ARM64 and Z15 as well as
   AWS, Azure and Google Cloud.

     https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-20-04-lts-arrives


<< contents of /etc/motd >>>


Last login: Sun May 17 21:41:54 2020 from 37.30.54.65
```

Then I changed setting `UsePAM` to  `no` and the result is:

```
Last login: Sun May 17 21:41:54 2020 from 37.30.54.65
```

I want to keep `UsePAM` as `no` and still see my welcome screen.

Comment: In general, you want to use PAM on most Linux systems because you want PAM session processing.  Not using it can have security implications.  Can you explain why you don't want to use it here?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like PAM is normally taking care of displaying `/etc/motd` on your system.

If you set `UsePAM no` in `sshd_config`, you must also set `PrintMotd yes` to make `sshd` print `/etc/motd` when not using PAM.

Note that Ubuntu uses `pam_motd.so` which can build up the Message of the Day from multiple sources (`/etc/motd`, `/etc/motd.d/*` and possibly other things produced by the `update-motd` scripts... `/var/motd.dynamic` or something similar, if I recall correctly?).

`sshd`'s MOTD routine may be simpler, so you'll have to make sure the full message is in `/etc/motd`.

Comment: `PrintMotd yes` does not help unfortunately. I have no source under `/etc/motd*`

Comment: And my message lies ofc in `/etc/motd`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not allowed to comment - this is not strictly an answer. I had the same problem. I wanted to disable PAM because I didn't want to enable anything but public key authentication. But of course, you can enable PAM and set

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

So I reenabled PAM and now I have MOTD again. Not sure how to enable MOTD without PAM (which is why this isn't really an answer, but *may* be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

I also want to keep `UsePAM` as `no` and still see my welcome screen.

It seems the location of `motd`-files changed to `/etc/update-motd.d/`, and you should be able to see the welcome screen using `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/`.

You can add `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` to e.g. the bottom of your `~/.profile` to see it whenever you login.

Inspired by: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/rymit7rzif-view-the-motd-after-login-in-ubuntu